# How to profile release apk generated by react-native project?

Tags: react-native, apk, release

In debug apk, I am able to open chrome debugger (v8 engine) and able to take snapshots. But I want to try with release apk. is it possible to do with release apk?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot debug an Application compiled with Release build command.